# Shall I answer Yes/No to this question?

Tags: questions

I'm filling an application which asks the following question:

**You have not attended the X company Selection Process in the last 6 months. ***  Yes/No

I've not attended any selection process. So, shall I say Yes/No to the question.?

Shall I say `Yes` since the statment is correct or shall I say `no` since I've not attended any such process?

Other similar statement in the application I find difficult is:

**You have declared break in studies/work experience and pending backlogs, if any, during your academics.**

Is it Yes/No given that I don't have any backlogs...and I filled everything correctly..?

Other question in the applications which might give you a clue are these:

**1.You have considered only the Marks/CGPA obtained during the normal duration of the course for calculating Obtained/Total Marks/CGPA.**

**2. You have completed each of the above mentioned academic courses in the stipulated time as specified by your University/Institute and as per X selection guidelines and do not have any extended education.**

For above two questions, the answers are unequivocally Yes.

Comment: You should mail them and tell them to write better application forms. I would think the question needs a "is that correct?"

Comment: Leave it blank and add a note on the continuation sheet! Or: look at the surrounding questions -- do they all want a "Yes" answer? Or "No"? That might give a clue.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I can't because....this is a must answer question

Comment: @AndrewLeach other statements are positive questions..they don't have 'not' in the sentence for ex: `"The Marks/CGPA Obtained" entered by you for each of the above mentioned academic qualifications has been secured in the first attempt.`

Comment: I suggest you ring them and ask.

Comment: Yes seems more convinving,i agree with colo.This is an example  of yes-no paradox and leading question.

Comment: Leading questions should be avoided while forming a questionnaire(in this case an applicant form) and a pilot run could be done to test their viability.backlog's answer is no (since you don't have pending backlogs),there are better examples of leading questions than these(in which there is no possible way to ascertain fully the possibility of one answer)

Comment: Are you trying to promote yourself here? There are better ways.(unequivocally yes)

Comment: @Argot what would I get by promoting myself here...I don't have enough knowledge....not sure what to use...tell me the other way..will edit the question...thank you...

Comment: @pinkpanther that was a stupid joke on my part.(my sense of humor)

Comment: Is there a "If no, give details" or "If yes, give details"? That might give you a clue about what no/yes are "meant to mean" in their context.

Comment: @starsplusplus no...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These questions are basically statements (not grammatically questions) in a **true/false** format. Some questionnaires would offer *True/False* or *T/F* as the answer options.

In this  case, if the statement is *true*, answer **yes**. If the statement is *false*, answer **no**.

Based on the information you have given, the answer to Question 1 is **yes**, and the answer to Question 2 is **no**.

If there is room on the form, and you want to take the time, you could write

> *Q1: No, I have not.* (You could also say *Yes, I have not*, but that might be a bit confusing)

For Question 2, you would have to say

> *Q2: No, I have not.*

As several other commentators have suggested, the questionnaire is not the most clear.

Comment: Thanks...It's an online application...so I can't write anything...

Answer (score 1):

**Question:**

> You have not attended the X company Selection Process in the last 6
>   months.

**Answer:**
"Yes! I have NOT attended the X company selection process."

**Question:**

> Have you attended the X company Selection Process in the last 6
>   months.

**Answer:**
"No! i have not attended the X company process."

Answer (score 0):

You should answer Yes, because you agree with that sentence.

Here "You have declared break in studies/work experience and pending backlogs, if any, during your academics" you should answer **No**. You don't agree with that.

Comment: What about this? `You have declared break in studies/work experience and pending backlogs, if any, during your academics.`   Given that I don't have any backlogs...